# Kdiff3 FSPathMakeRef(app_path_location) failed with error -43 Mac OS-X

Tags: macos, kdiff3

I am trying to open kdiff3 from the terminal and pass two local file as argument of kdiff3 (not in git repo). Kdiff3 I am using as git diff tool thats works perfectly fine to compare my current version and repo head version. However, the problem occur when I run the kdiff3 with local file (not in git repo) as a argument from terminal then I get an error saying that, `FSPathMakeRef(local_kdiff_path/kdiff3.app ) failed with error -43.` FYI, kdiff3.app path location is exactly same as I define for git diff tool or alias. Following two ways I tried, but none of them work :

```
alias kd2='open -a "local_kdiff_path/kdiff3.app" $1 $2'
alias kd3='sudo open -a "local_kdiff_path/kdiff3.app/Contents/MacOS/kdiff3" $1 $2'
```

Please suggest me how I can resolve this issue ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the path you define in your `bash script` or `.bash_profile` can not find the application location. Even though the argument is easily accessible in Linux or Windows but for mac specific the script is bit different.

**MAC OS-X Solution**

Create a simple bash script as follows and provide the arguments

```
kdiff_installed_folder/kdiff3.app/Contents/MacOS/kdiff3 "$1" "$2" "$4"
```

**Linux Solution**

Add following commands in the .bashrc or .aliases file

```
alias kd '/app/kdiff3/0.9.96/RHEL64/kdiff3'
alias kd1 '/app/kdiff3/0.9.96/RHEL64/kdiff3 $1' 
alias kd2 '/app/kdiff3/0.9.96/RHEL64/kdiff3 $1 $2'
```

**Windows Solution**

If you install the `Git-bash` add following line in the .bashrc file

```
alias kd='"C:/Program Files/KDiff3/kdiff3.exe"'
alias kd1='"C:/Program Files/KDiff3/kdiff3.exe" $1'
alias kd2='"C:/Program Files/KDiff3/kdiff3.exe" $1 $2'
```